# Running Hadoop On Ubuntu Linux (Multi-Node Cluster)

Tags: linux, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I've implemented hadoop on 2 clusters,but i cant run TaskTracker & DataNode & jobTracker,so icant run copyFromLocal command on hdfs.i use a hadoop 2.6.5.i run jps command after run the start-all.sh command:(on master)

```
ResourceManager
NameNode
jps
JobHistoryServer
NodeManager
```

and i run jps command :(on slave)

```
jps
NodeManager
```

can anyone help me to run the TaskTracker & DataNode & jobTracker?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

> TaskTracker & jobTracker

These services do not exist on Hadoop2 and above, and are replaced by Node+ResourceManager services of YARN.

You can run `start-dfs.sh` to start a Datanode, and you should look at the respective datanode log files to determine why it can't start.

For example, you must format the namenode before a Datanode can start (`hadoop namenode -format`)